# when I run npm run dev I am getting error

Tags: laravel

this is my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "serve": "node --version",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node your-script.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "core-js": "^2.6.5",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^0.10.0np",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.22"
    }
}
```

and the error is

$ npm run dev

> @ dev C:\xampp\htdocs\laspp
> npm run development

> @ development C:\xampp\htdocs\laspp
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

95% emitting

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                                                                                                      5:48:21 PM
These dependencies were not found:

* jquery in ./resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js
* bootstrap-sass in ./resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js
* vue in ./resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save jquery bootstrap-sass vue
            Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
       /js/app.js    603 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app    
mix-manifest.json  32 bytes          [emitted]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Natty\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-13T00_48_22_038Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Natty\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-13T00_48_22_141Z-debug.log
```

**finally**, I tried this

- rm -rf node-modules
- rm packageson-lock.json
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install

but it does not work

Comment: Did you try `npm install`?

Comment: yes I tried npm install

Comment: Please check it here. Maybe you have the same problem

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203196/these-dependencies-were-not-found-error-in-vue-js

Comment: checked but its different problem

Answer (score 0):

Looking your error and your package.json, this error tell you this :

> To install them, you can run: npm install --save jquery bootstrap-sass vue

Can you do this and restart your `npm run development` ?

Comment: 95% emitting                                                                         

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors                                                                                                                                      7:56:52 PM
These relative modules were not found:

* ../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot in ./~/css-loader?{"url":true}!./~/postcss-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expan:true}!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

Comment: Have you got this error with npm run development or install ?

Comment: with npm run dev